# How to use 'overrides' theme when using seed prefix with createGenerateClassName in Material ui

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

We are extending material ui theme, but when doing :

```
 const theme = createMuiTheme({
  overrides: { MuiOutlinedInput: { root: { backgroundColor: 'red' } } },
})
```

the changes dont apply. We are also using `createGenerateClassName`:

```
const generateClassName = createGenerateClassName({
  productionPrefix: 'c',
  seed: 'corp',
})
```

So, when taking a look at the html code, I noticed the class MuiOutlinedInput is now `corp-MuiOutlinedInput-root`, so we decided to use the following override instead:

```
   const theme = createMuiTheme({
      overrides: { "corp-MuiOutlinedInput": { root: { backgroundColor: 'red' } } },
    })
```

But it does not work either. Any clue?

Comment: I'd be faster for everyone to help you if you can include a codesandbox example of your problem. I also want to see which component doesn't work for you.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Did you ever figure this out?